# Must async methods be supported by OS or is async program level feature

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Tutorials sometimes point implementation of own async methods as for example this code:

```
async public static Task GetHttpResponseAsync()
{
   using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
   {
       HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(...);
       Console.WriteLine(response.Something);
   }            
}
```

what is clear to me is **how async work generally**, but none of tutorials explains how internally are implemented

```
httpClient.GetAsync(...);
```

which is really important to understand how asynchoronus code works in details. What make me curious is if internall operations of GetAsync (those method or other async method) are registered in some kind of container where this code is executed? Are async methods must be supported by operating system (f.e it uses windows api)? If I would like to implement my own asynchronous file downloader (from disk and without essential part from .NET framework), how would I implement it, should I register my method somewhere for further invocation?

It's pretty clear for me that internally, compiler makes state machine and after DoSomething() method do what it have to, it just invoke this state machine again to resume executing code after await.

Also what is unclear for me is that how async code can run on same thread. I think that maintaining state machine must be on the same thread but how the code from httpClient.GetAsync() can be run on the same thread and doesn't interrupt other operations (f.e gui). There must be something that make this code runs on separate thread (in all cases). Am I wrong? What I missed?

Additional explanation of my question: In JavaScript, as far as I know and understand, async methods works by registering them in some kind of container (which runs them one by one on separate thread) which executes this method. After execution of the method complete, result is returned to user context, It's clear for me, Is that work in the same way here?

Comment: `async/await` is a program level feature to make writing code for interfacing with awaitable objects more ergonomic. Asynchronicity itself, however, is a feature of your interface to any entities your program is communicating with. A synchronous interface makes you wait for whatever response you're seeking, whereas an asynchronous interface accepts your request and provides a mechanism for calling you back when ready. Asynchronous interfaces translate well to awaitable objects, whereas synchronous interfaces do not.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin So, there must be something that runs code on separate thread and after that, force user thread (f.e ui thread) to call that async methods once again to switch state machine and run remaining code?

Comment: Well, with an HTTP request, the "separate thread" would be a server possibly millions of miles away. Your program would be expending no computational effort (not even in a different thread), and would be free to do other things like responding to user input. Regarding "force user thread", no: async/await is not pre-emptive. Async/await can be implemented entirely without reliance on any kind of threads available. It is only a transformation mechanism that lets you break up methods into steps and use continuation passing without thinking about it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short, true asynchrony must be provided at the OS level.  As you've noted, `async`/`await` is a language level feature that uses compiler generated state machines to "break up" your method into pieces that can run asynchronously, but it relies on OS primitives (interrupts, threads) to actually perform this work in an asynchronous manner.

However, it's important to note that there will often **not** be a thread created to handle your async operation.  I'll defer to this expertly-written article to describe why this is the case: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

On Windows, the primary mechanism for performing asynchronous work is with [I/O Completion Ports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx). This is a Windows API that is used under the hood by many .NET types, including the `HttpClient` you're using.

Note that for non-I/O operations, you can also always use [Threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516(v=vs.85).aspx), or better yet, the [Thread Pool API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686766(v=vs.85).aspx), to perform background work that will complete asynchronously.

The [ReadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx) (or newer [ReadFileEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365468(v=vs.85).aspx)) function in the Windows API is designed to work with async I/O.  When you call `ReadFile`, you can use the `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag and pass an `OVERLAPPED` structure to the `lpOverlapped` argument, which enables async reads. I would encourage you to use this API to design your file downloader.

---

In summary:

- There will not always be a thread created for async operations.
- async/await is a language feature, but relies on various Windows APIs to achieve true asynchrony.
- If the work you are doing is I/O bound, consider using Asynchronous I/O: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365683(v=vs.85).aspx
- If the work you are doing is CPU bound, consider using Threading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684841(v=vs.85).aspx
- Now that .NET Core is open source on GitHub, you can actually inspect the source code to see what's going on under the hood.  Here is [HttpClient.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs), which uses `HttpMessageHandler.cs` -> `HttpClientHandler.Windows.cs` -> `WinHttpHandler.cs` -> `Interop.winhttp.cs` -> PInvoke into the [WinHTTP API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384252(v=vs.85).aspx) native DLL -> Winsock sockets with an I/O completion port.